# Numerical Algorithms

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am recently started looking into continuous matrix concepts but I am not understanding simple example like. Suppose I have a time-varying matrix A(t); I evaluate the determinant at t = 0 and t = 1 and find
that they have different signs. Give a method to find the time t at which A(t) becomes singular.
and number of iterations required for n decimal digits of accuracy. at least can you refer the resources to solve this kind of solutions?

Comment: Look up the Bisection Method.